# AngularJS show value if filter works, otherwise, show original value

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a value returned from a service that is a date that can be normally parsed into a date format. In certain circumstances, the data is returned in a "blurred out" format "*****" something like that.

My problem is my date parsing won't display that "*****" and I would like to.

```
{{person.dateOfBirth | date: "MM/dd/yyyy" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write own filter, which either returns original value (in case of asterisks), or will call original dateFilter and returns that value.

Comment: I was secretly hoping there was an alternate, easier way of doing that, ha

Comment: There is, e.g. do it in controller or directive, but since this rather belongs to view's responsibility, I'd choose filter and keep it in view... but I understand ;)